# Why app fall into infinite loop when setting a property?

Tags: ios, core-data, properties, swift, option-type

**1)** Here is my custom UITableViewCell defined:

```
class UserTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var ou: OU? {
    set(newOU) {

        println(newOU)

        self.ou = newOU
    }   
}
```

**2)** I am passing a NSManagedObject to the cell

```
let s = sth.filteredSetUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "someAttribute = true"))
let ou: OU = s.anyObject() as OU
cell.ou = ou
```

**3)** It keeps write out this log message several times, like app would fall into an infinite loop.

> Optional( (entity: OU; id: 0x7a7e3590
>   
>   ; data: {
>       someAttribute = 1; }))

## Conclusion

Basically I needed only a simple stored property, without any fancy stuff:

```
class UserTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var ou: OU?
}
```

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: Think about it. You're setting the property inside the property's setter. If you just want to print the value when it changes, use willSet or didSet.

Comment: In regard to #4 In SWIFT providing a ? after variable declaration indicates it is Optional. I am GUESSING this is what the log is referring to. Have you tried removing that and seeing if the Optional message still appears in the log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because the setter that you wrote calls the setter. self.ou = ... calls the setter again, so you got yourself a nice infinite recursion. That is as long as the stack lasts.